# UIImageView doesn't update image while in for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have an  Array of CGRect `arr`, and I want to draw those rectangles onto an image in a for loop. This is the code:

```
 __block UIImage *procImage=image;


for(int i=0;i<arr.count;i++){
    CGRect rect=[[arr objectAtIndex:i] CGRectValue];
    procImage=[self drawText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i] inImage:procImage atPoint:CGPointMake(rect.origin.x,rect.origin.y-rect.size.height) withRect:rect];

    [self.imageView setImage:procImage];

    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

        procImage=[self drawText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i] inImage:procImage atPoint:CGPointMake(rect.origin.x,rect.origin.y-rect.size.height) withRect:rect];

        [self.imageView setImage:procImage];


    }];
}
```

This is the `drawText:` function

```
-(UIImage*) drawText:(NSString*) text
         inImage:(UIImage*)  image
         atPoint:(CGPoint)   point
        withRect:(CGRect)rectangle
{

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height)];
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, image.size.width, image.size.height);

[text drawInRect:CGRectIntegral(rect) withAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor greenColor],
                                                       NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:50]}
 ];
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextStrokeRect(context, rectangle);

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return newImage;
}
```

The problem is the imageView only update its image when the for loop finished. I want to create a nice animation that updates the image for everytime a new rectangle is drawn during the for loop.

## Edit

I had simplified the code. In my case, I was performing an OCR process for each text block so it would take a lot of time (maybe several minutes). During that time I want to show the users something of the process instead of a dead interface for each time a text block is done.

Comment: Instead of using a for loop use a repeating `NSTimer`.  This will give the run loop a chance to render your changes.  Also your for loop will complete so quickly that the changes would be invisible anyway

Comment: You beat me to the punch. I was typing out a too-long-winded answer as you typed your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear what effect you are after. Do you want a short delay between drawing each image and text in it's target rectangle so they stack up?

You have 2 problems. First, nothing is actually rendered to the screen until your code returns. Thus when you run a loop like that, the drawing calls just stack up, you return from your code, and then everything gets rendered to the screen.

Even if you fix that, your second problem is that drawing image after image after image to the screen will be so fast that the user's eyes won't see the individual steps.

If I'm right about what you're trying to do, you could do it this way instead.

Add an instance variable to keep track of the index of the current image. Set it to zero.

Write a method that draws the current image and text at the current rectangle, then increments the index instance variable. If there are more entries in your array of images/rectangles, have the method call itself on the main thread after a short delay using the GCD call dispatch_after. That would return control to the main thread and let the new drawing render to the screen, and give the user time to see that drawing before the next one is drawn.

### EDIT:

As @Paulw11 says in his comment you could also re-invoke your method using a repeating timer and simply invalidate it once you run out of entries in your array.

Comment: Thank you! I edited my question for a clearer situation. Also, I don't know what did you mean by "when my code returns"? Was it about the NSOperation? I had tried change the image without putting those code into the NSOperation block, but nothing really happens.

Answer (score 2):

Create your images array and cache it. Then use `UIImageView` `animationImages` property to store the array of images you have created and let `UIImageView` handle the animation. Constructing an image every single time is process intensive.

**Apple Documentation:**

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImageView/animationImages

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I edited the question to provide more information. The point here is not just the animation. I wanted the users to see some changes during my complex and heavy process instead of a still image.